# Trespass and the police

Tags: trespass

Can a US cop ask a land owner if a person is trespassing if no complaint has been made? i.e. can they ask a shop owner if a person is trespassing in their car park or outside the shop?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course. *Anyone* can walk up to a shop owner and ask them pretty much whatever questions they want; police have just as much of a right to do that as anyone else. The shop owner doesn't have to answer, but police are free to ask.

Comment: Police have the same rights as any other citizen, unless specifically forbidden in the few restrictions and obligations borne from their public servant status. They also have several other abilities necessary to perform their duties.